# Laravel 4 - JQuery UI Datepicker causing NotFoundHttpException

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, laravel-4

For some reason when I try to use the datepicker() feature from JQuery UI in Laravel 4 I am getting a NotFoundHttpException error with my form. I thought it might be because of the format of the date so I already changed my datepicker to display in yy-mm-dd by changing the script to `$('#orderDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd" });` but it didn't fix the problem. The error only occurs when I include inputs that are tied to the datepicker. I have used JQuery UI with other projects but never with Laravel 4 as I'm still pretty new to it. If anyone could point out where I'm going wrong it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Here is (the relevant part of) my view:

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')

{{ Form::model($order, array('route'=>array('order-edit-post', $order->id), 'name', '=', 'orderForm', 'id', '=', 'orderForm')) }}

        {{ Form::label('order_name', 'Order Name:')}}
        {{ Form::text('order_name') }}
        @if($errors->has('order_name'))
            {{ $errors->first('order_name') }}
        @endif

        {{ Form::label('orderDate', 'Order Date:')}}
        {{ Form::text('orderDate') }}
        @if($errors->has('orderDate'))
            {{ $errors->first('orderDate') }}
        @endif

        {{ Form::label('dueDate', 'Due Date:')}}
        {{ Form::text('dueDate') }}
        @if($errors->has('dueDate'))
            {{ $errors->first('dueDate') }}
        @endif
```

Controller:

```
public function postEdit($id){
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
            array(
                'order_name'            =>'required',
                'st_address'            =>'required',
                'date_order'            =>'required',
                'date_post'         =>'required',
            )
        );
    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('order-edit')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput()
                ->with('global', 'You done messed up.');
    }   else {
        /*Edit Order*/
        $order          = Order::find($id);                 
        $order->order_name      = Input::get('order_name');
        $order->date_order      = Input::get('date_order');
        $order->date_post       = Input::get('date_post');*/

        if($order->save()){
            return Redirect::route('home')
                    ->with('global', 'Your order has been    edited.');
        }
    }

    return Redirect::route('home')
            ->with('global', 'Your order could not be edited.');

}
```

And finally Route:

```
/*Edit Order (POST)*/
                Route::post('/orders/{orders}/edit', array(
                    'as'    => 'order-edit-post',
                    'uses'  => 'OrderController@postEdit',
                ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably get a better piece of advice from somebody else, but in this sort of situation I have made use of intentional code sabotage.  If I insert

```
throw new Exception ('DESCRIPTION OF PLACE IN CODE');
```

immediately before a line of code I think may be bombing and then move it to immediately after, I can determine if the crash is triggered by that line - the crash will forestall the Exception.  In your case, I'd be trying this before and after the if statements that trigger redirects.  My suspicion is that the redirect to order-edit is what's failing - any chance you don't have it defined in your route.php file?

Comment: I'm happy to hear about better methods for doing that sort of testing without installing and learning an additional piece of software (I'll look into that on my next project...).

Comment: Thanks, that idea helped narrow it down to my validator. I forgot to add the $id, so it should look like: 
`if($validator->fails()){
   return Redirect::route('order-edit', $id)
     ->withErrors($validator)
     ->withInput()
     ->with('global', 'You done messed up.');
  } else {`

Comment: Ah, forgot to pass the parameter.  Yeah, that's an easy mistake, I do that kind of thing all the time.